# Getting User information from foreign key in Jinja. Only getting user id

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am having trouble accessing user information from a foreign key. Here are my Models:

```
class User(UserMixin, db.Model): 
    _tablename_ = 'user'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True,) 
    email = db.Column(db.String(200), unique=True)
    password = db.Column(db.String(30))
    
    cases = db.relationship('Case',  backref='user' , lazy=True)
    
    
class Case(db.Model):
    _tabename_ = 'case'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    status = db.Column(db.String(20), default="Open")
    priority = db.Column(db.String(20), default="Low")
    date_created = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.datetime.now().date())
    case_nickname = db.Column(db.String(100))
    case_address = db.Column(db.String(100))
    case_description = db.Column(db.String(100))
    comments = db.Column(db.JSON)
    
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer(), db.ForeignKey("user.id"))
```

In my html file I am able to access the user.id like this:

```
<td>{{case.user_id}}</td>
```

But when I try to access email like this nothing comes up:

```
<td>{{case.user_id.email}}</td>
```

How can I access the user information in that case without adding another query?

Comment: You accessing `user_id` not `user`, which is the `backref` in your `relationship`.

Comment: I tried that already. When I try to access with case.user I get this error: jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'dict object' has no attribute 'user'.

Comment: Then add `user` as a `relationship` in the `Case` class.

Answer (score 0):

It'll depend on how you do your marshaling too, but you need to have the `user`  attribute as a relationship.

```
class Case(db.Model):
    _tabename_ = 'case'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    ...

    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer(), db.ForeignKey("user.id"))
    user = db.relationship('User',  backref='cases' , lazy=True)
```